# Show the existence and evaluate $F'(t)$ knowing $F(t)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partial-fractions

We are given the following expression :

$$F_1(t) = \int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{\cos(x)dx}{(1+t\cos(x))^2}}$$
$$F_2(t) = \int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\log(1+tx)}{1+x^2}}dx$$

> Show the existence and evaluate $F_1'(t)$ and $F_2'(t)$

I don't know how I can prove the existence of both  $F_1'(t)$ and $F_2'(t)$.

To evaluate $F_1'(t)$ and $F_2'(t)$, I thought that using the partial fraction decomposition method could help us but I'm not sure.

Any help would be a lot appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know theorems that allow you to differentiate under the integral sign ?

Comment: Hello @TheSilverDoe, thanks for your time in calculus we saw the leibzeig integral rule ? but can we apply it here ?

Comment: Yes we can apply it, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement , we satisfy all the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the integrand is $\mathcal{C}^1([0,1])$, if $t>-1$ we can use the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) and get
$$F'_2(t)=\int_0^1 \frac{\partial \frac{\log (t x+1)}{x^2+1}}{\partial t} \, dx=\int_0^1 \frac{x}{\left(x^2+1\right) (t x+1)} \, dx=\frac{\pi  t-4 \log (t+1)+\log (4)}{4 t^2+4}$$

Comment: This is correct, but maybe you should precise *why* you are allowed to differentiate under the integral sign ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I edited my answer. Is it OK, now?

Comment: thanks for the edit, but $\log(1+tx)$ is not everywhere defined, is it ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe $t$ must be greater than $-1$, right?